# Can't call function inside setState()

Tags: flutter

I was working on an app this morning but I couldn't get around this issue.  The code is this one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String date = 'MARCH 2021';
    Color dateColor = Colors.white;
    void changeColor() {
      dateColor = Colors.blue;
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calendar',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text(date))),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            primary: false,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: dateColor,
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Text('1')),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        this.setState(() {
                          changeColor();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('2'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('3'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('4'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('5'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('6'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('7'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('8'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('9'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('10'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('11'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('12'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('13'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('14'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('15'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('16'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('17'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('18'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('19'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('20'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('21'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('22'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('23'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('24'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('25'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('26'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('27'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('28'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('29'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('30'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('31'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I want a way so that, when I press the button, the color of the pressed Container changes from white to blue and all the other Containers switch back to white. The problem is that when I actually press the button nothing happens. I'd like to know why. I know that the code is pretty long, and most likely inefficient, but I'm a complete newbie regarding flutter. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `dateColor` outside the build method:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color dateColor = Colors.white;
    void changeColor() {
      dateColor = Colors.blue;
    }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String date = 'MARCH 2021';
    return .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I just segregated your code and now it works. Its better this way so ya don't have to rebuild the whole app UI and rather, just the widget that changes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final date = 'MARCH 2021';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calendar',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text(date))),
          body: CalenderWidget(),
    ));
  }
}
      
class CalenderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalenderWidgetState createState() => _CalenderWidgetState();
}
        
class _CalenderWidgetState extends State<CalenderWidget> {
  Color dateColor = Colors.white;
  void changeColor() {
    dateColor = Colors.blue;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
            primary: false,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: dateColor,
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Text('1')),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          changeColor();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('2'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('3'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('4'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('5'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('6'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('7'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('8'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('9'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('10'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('11'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('12'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('13'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('14'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('15'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('16'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('17'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('18'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('19'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('20'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('21'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('22'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('23'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('24'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('25'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('26'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('27'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('28'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('29'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('30'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: const Text('31'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to previous answer by [@rkdupr0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11566145/rkdupr0n) - you should use 'collection for' to generate dates 2-31:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final date = 'MARCH 2021';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calendar',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text(date))),
          body: CalenderWidget(),
    ));
  }
}
      
class CalenderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalenderWidgetState createState() => _CalenderWidgetState();
}
        
class _CalenderWidgetState extends State<CalenderWidget> {
  Color dateColor = Colors.white;
  void changeColor() {
    dateColor = Colors.blue;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
            primary: false,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: dateColor,
                        ),
                        child: const Center(child: Text('1')),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          changeColor();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    for (var i=2;i<=31;i++)
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Text('$i'),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was about to post on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Collection for and collection if are great for this. In case you need something more complex, create a function that returns List<Widget>, and then just use spread operator (...):
<Widget>[
    MyWidget(1),
   MyWidget(20,
   ... someFunctionReturningListOfWidgets()
]